# Illegal Statement Exception : Already Connected ,A connection Through Url

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

> Hello All,

In my project,I need to start WEB-APP through a link to maintain some security.

This is my URL 
https://xxxxx:8443/Project_Folder/Servlet_Name

> Code of java File

```
public class ConnectWebApp {

public String makeConnection(String urlData) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        String xmlOutput = "";
        String url = "";
        String tail = "Servlet_Name";
        String str1 = "";

        String SERVER = "xxxxxx";
        String SERVERPORT = "8443";

        url = "https://" + SERVER + ":" + SERVERPORT + "/Project_Folder/" + tail;

                try {
            URL connectUrl = new URL(url);
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            } };
            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) connectUrl.openConnection();
            System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(urlData);
            wr.flush();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            if (buffer.toString().equals(null)) {

                System.exit(1);
            }

            System.err.println(buffer.toString());
            System.exit(0);

            wr.close();
            rd.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error while making connection ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return str1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
/* For SSL Certificate*/
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {

            public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                if (hostname.equals("xxxxx")) {
                    System.out.println(hostname);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        String urlData = URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("Run", "UTF-8");

        ConnectWebApp C = new ConnectWebApp();
        C.makeConnection(urlData);
    }}
```

It give the Response code for this method `HttpsURLConnection#getResponseCode` = **404 (Not Found).**

I am using **Apache Tomcatv7.0** , **java_version (6.0,For some technical reason)**. What are the possibility of this cause?

**In Web_App,**

My source is a WAR file, I just imported it and deployed it on the server.
Give me some solution.

Comment: Wants to maintain some security, "Install the all-trusting trust manager"

Comment: Why is the error stated in your title not the same as in your question? Anyway for the 404 you should 1) verify connectivity : try pinging the server from the machine running the client ; 2) check the server's access logs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Connectvity is clear @Aaron . My doubt is that, when I import a WAR file, the class files which are available is not showing in the Eclipse Workspace. So, is that possible to give this 404(resource isn't available) error?

Comment: Well if the was doesn't contain the ressources you try to access, it's sure to pose a problem. Now I don't know how Eclipse handles importing war files, and it's pretty sure to fail retrieving java code unless the source is included in the war, which is rare. You could check its content with a zip editor, java packages always are zips with specific structure.

Comment: You should try to connect to your webApp with another client (maybe SoapUI?) just to check that the server side is ok. We can't really help you on that point since all you posted concerns the client side.

Comment: @Aaron yep, your response is helpful, I do not have access for the server logs also, I am in the start-up. I checked the WAR file by changing into zip, it have all those class files, which are specified in the web.xml. Thank you.